# C26495 Variable 'Employee::age' is uninitialized. Always initialize a member variable (type.6)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, constructor, scope

this is my code:-

```
#include<iostream>

using std::string;

//bydefault private cant access attributes outside class

class Employee{

public:

    string name;

    string company;

    int age=0;

    void Introduce() {

        std::cout << "my age is- " << age << std::endl;

    }

    Employee(string company, string name, int age) {

        name = name;

        company = company;

        age = age;

    }

};



int main() {

    Employee emp1 = Employee("bww","susmit",24);

    emp1.Introduce();

    //Employee emp2;

    //same example

}
```

Output is my age is 0

I want it to be what I entered emp1 args to be

please help.

Comment: What do you expect assignments like `age = age;` to do?

Comment: `age = age;` -- I am surprised you weren't confused by this, given you have a parameter and a member variable with the same name.

Comment: You should change your coding style so that parameters and members have different names.

Answer (score 4):

This constructor

```
Employee(string company, string name, int age) {

    name = name;

    company = company;

    age = age;

}
```

is incorrect. Within the body of the constructor you are assigning parameters to themselves. It is because the parameters hide data members with the same name within the body of the constructor.

At least you should write

```
Employee(string company, string name, int age) {

    this->name = name;

    this->company = company;

    this->age = age;

}
```

But it would be even better to use a mem-initializer list like

```
Employee(const std::string &company, const std::string &name, int age) 
    : name( name ), company( company ), age( age )
{
}
```

And in main you may write

```
Employee emp1("bww","susmit",24);
```

instead of

```
Employee emp1 = Employee("bww","susmit",24);
```

As for the function `Introduce` then it is better to declare and define it the following way

```
std::ostream & Introduce( std::ostream &os = std::cout ) const
{
    os << "my age is- " << age << std::endl;
    return os;
}
```

Also there is no great sense to declare these data members

```
string name;

string company;

int age=0;
```

as having a public access. You could declare them as having private access.

Also as your class does not have the default constructor then this member initialization within the class definition

```
int age=0;
```

is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

Your constructor just assigns the arguments given to the constructor to themselves:

```
Employee(string company, string name, int age) {
                 //              ^
                 //              |
    name = name; // -------------+ both left and right name refer to the argument
    company = company;
    age = age;
}
```

You could solve it by using a different name for the constructor arguments (or by being explicit using `this->member = ...`) or by using the [member initializer-list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor):

```
Employee(string company, string name, int age) : // colon starts the member init-list
    name(name),        // The first name refers to the member varible (this->name)
    company(company),  // and the second refers to the constructor argument
    age(age)           //
{
    // constructor body can now be empty
}
```